# Tkinter, GUI and global variables

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

I'm having trouble passing an argument to my second function, which is defined in my first variable within a class.

In function 1 `open_file()` I define `global fp` which is a user input filepath. In function 2 `split_lines()` I have the first argument as that filepath `fp` which I want to read off the same file defined from function 1. In my button for that second function I can't get it to work off `fp` as it says it's not defined.

```
def open_file(self):  # Defines the function that opens the user's file in specific location.
    global fp
    fp = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
    if not fp:
        return
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(fp, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"Linestring Compiler V1.0 - {fp}")

# Defines the function that reads, delimits and quantifies the data.
def split_lines(fp, delimiter, remove = '^[0-9.]+$'):
    for line in fp:
        tokens = line.split(delimiter)
        tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
        clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
        print(clean_list)
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    #with open(user_filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
    text = clean_list.read()
    txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
```

This is my button:

```
btn_compile = tk.Button(frm_buttons, text="Compile Lines", command=Sequence.split_lines(fp, "/"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The PROBLEM is that you are not passing the `split_lines` function.  You are CALLING the function at the time you create the button, and passing its RESULT to `command=`.  At the time it is called, `open_file` hasn't been called yet.

You need a lambda:

```
btn_compile = tk.Button(frm_buttons, text="Compile Lines", command=lambda: Sequence.split_lines(fp, "/"))
```

Comment: @Time Roberts, thank you - I was able to have the button passed through the button using a lambda. Although the issue now is that Its reading the filepath and not the contents of the file, is there a way to correct that?

Comment: edit to above: It is reading the contents, but only rewriting the last line into the `txt_edit` window,

Comment: Yes, because you reset `clean_list` every time through the loop.  Perhaps you wanted `clean_list = []` before the loop, and `clean_list.extend( list(filter(...)))`.

Comment: @Time Roberts, I appreciate you helping me. I'm new to tkinter! This works, although now it's re-writes everything onto one line instead of the original data being multi line.

Comment: Yes, you are removing the newlines when you do your `split`.  You will have to re-add them, but I'm not sure of your need.  Maybe `clean_list = append( ''.join( filter(...)))`, then do `'\n'.join(clean_list)` later.

Comment: The initial data set has multiple lines of ABC/DEF/GHI/ etc. I split that by "/" and remove unnecessary data. Then I'd like to re print that in the text widget.